# Would possible bankruptcy of Alitalia affect my plans?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, alitalia

Do I have to worry that my holiday won't happen because of the financial problems within Alitalia? It's all over the news that Alitalia faces bankruptcy. If it does, what would happen to my flight to Japan?

Comment: Alitalia in financial trouble? Well, I suppose today *is* a day ending in *y*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Associated Press](http://abcnews.go.com/Lifestyle/wireStory/alitalia-expected-start-bankruptcy-procedures-47005278) I wouldn't worry:

> Such a scenario could result in shedding unprofitable routes, most likely predominantly domestic ones, to competitors, and selling off aircraft to help pay creditors.

Long haul is the most profitable so I wouldn't worry. For example when Air Berlin was bleeding money like no tomorrow they [restructured](https://www.ft.com/content/2f1319f4-fb86-32e9-a819-240fb39a87d9) similarly:

> Air Berlin said that its “touristic” business – its charter operations – would be combined in a separate unit “with a view to evaluate strategic options”. [...] Air Berlin will continue to operate a “reduced core fleet” of 75 aircraft on long-haul routes from its two hubs in Berlin and Duesseldorf